# Dechirping in python

Tags: python, chirp

I have a piece of python code that creates a chirping signal and a downchirp signal. I would like to "dechirp" the chirped signal and my expectation is that doing so, I'll be left with a signal having just a single frequency.

I'm trying to establish what is happening in this video from the provided timestamp
https://youtu.be/NoquBA7IMNc?t=1860

I know that there is a "multiplication" with a complex conjugate of the chirp. But the term "multiplication" is not fully correct, am I right? You are mixing two signals with each different frequencies.

[image: upchirp times downchirp = dechirp]

The picture makes it look so easy and logical but somewhere I fail to obtain the right piece in my thoughts.

```
# Define the parameters
sampling_rate = 1000  # Samples per second
duration = 2  # Seconds
start_freq = 10  # Hz
end_freq = 100  # Hz

# Generate the chirp signal
t = np.linspace(0, duration, int(duration * sampling_rate), endpoint=False)
chirp_signal = scipy.signal.chirp(t, f0=start_freq, f1=end_freq, t1=duration, method='linear')

# Generate the reference signal
inverse_chirp_signal = scipy.signal.chirp(t, f0=end_freq, f1=start_freq, t1=duration, method='linear')

# Perform cross-correlation
dechirped_signal = scipy.signal.correlate(chirp_signal, inverse_chirp_signal, mode='same')

# Plot the dechirped signal
plt.plot(t, dechirped_signal)
plt.plot(t, chirp_signal)
plt.plot(t, inverse_chirp_signal)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Dechirped Signal')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

fft_values = np.fft.fft(dechirped_signal)
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(dechirped_signal), 1/sampling_rate)
magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(fft_values)

# Plot the frequency spectrum
plt.plot(frequencies[:len(frequencies)//2], magnitude_spectrum[:len(frequencies)//2])
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.title('Frequency Spectrum of Dechirped Signal')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This code first creates both a chirp signal and an inverse signal. However, the dechirped signal is not a single frequency signal and the fft does show that it isn't.

[image: orange and green are chirp and inverse chirp]
The picture shows 3 lines, orange (chirp), green (inverse chirp) and blue (dechirped) and for some reason the blue is way bigger but that is fine for now. As you can see, the blue signal increases in frequency as well, while I expect it to have a single frequency component. (Well, I think I expect that since the video tells me it should but a bit of clarification on why would be awesome, makes me learn!)

The frequency spectrum clearly shows that not a single frequency but multiple between 10 and 100 Hz are found.
[image: Dechirped signal frequency spectrum]

I can also do signal multiplication, which is suggested. So then rather than doing a correlation, I have the line:

```
dechirped_signal = chirp_signal * inverse_chirp_signal
```

Now my dechirped signal looks like:
[image: Dechirped signal in multiplication]

But that is clearly not a single frequency and not, as i expect, a nice sine wave. The frequency spectrum does look like this now, with a very clear peak at about 110 Hz

[image: Spectrum plot for multiplication]

To summarize my questions

1. what is the term for "multiplication" of these signals to dechirp them, since it is not a simple a * b multiplication in time domain?
2. why am I not obtaining just a single frequency after dechirping
3. why should I have only a single frequency component after dechirping

I assume that all signals here are ideal, just for comprehension.

Comment: dechirping really *is* multiplication with the complex conjugate in time domain, usually. The fact that you're doing a correlation after means you're kind of building a matched filter.

Comment: that means that dechirped_signal[0] = chirp_signal[0] * inverse_chirp_signal[0] and so on?

Comment: I updated my question with the simple multiplication as well. Would you maybe be so kind to add feedback?

Comment: @Mart You're defining your reference signal to start backwards in frequency. The reference signal is simply the complex conjugate of the chirp you want to transmit.

Comment: @Envidia Thanks for your answer, but isn't the complex conjugate not the time inverse in this case? If not, how then would I obtain the complex conjugate? I'm saying this because In LoRa, the symbol is multiplied with a downchirp (which is also referenced as the complex conjugate) so I'm confused.